# AngularUI Router - Unable to access States via URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

So having an issue with AngularUI Router. The problem I'm having is it's unable to access any states via entering the URL or refreshing while on a state other than home. The returned error is `Cannot GET /state-name` however the `ui-sref="state-name"` works perfectly fine.

Not using a Node server or Express routing, just Angular and running web server using Gulp-Connect.

**Technology:**

- AngularJS 1.5.3
- Angular UI 0.2.18
- Gulp 3.9.1

**Routes.js**

```
angular.module('myApp').config(function(
  $httpProvider,
  $stateProvider,
  $locationProvider,
  $urlRouterProvider
){
  $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true, requireBase: false});

  $stateProvider
    .state('home',{
      url:'/',
      templateUrl: 'path/to/home.tmpl.html'
  })
  .state('state-name',{
    url:'/state-name',
    templateUrl: 'path/to/state-name.tmpl.html'
  });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

Is there something I'm missing to allow for refreshing on a state or navigating via URL?

Comment: The state name is the name of your state, this is different to the URL which is specified by the `url` option as in your code. You give `ui-sref` a state name and it will generate a link to the corresponding URL

Comment: Apologies for the sloppy code. So I've updated the code to make it correct. Now the issue is I can get to links via ui-sref but still unable to access via url.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a state called `state-name` to be able to access it. From your state providers, I can't see any state with this name `state-name`. Currently your available states are `home` and `route_1`.

To access 'state-name', you need to add this state:

 `.state('state-name',{
      url:'/state-name',
      templateUrl: 'path/to/state-name.tmpl.html'
  })`

Comment: Apologies for the sloppy code. So I've updated the code to make it correct. Now the issue is I can get to links via ui-sref but still unable to access via url.

Answer (score 0):

For accessing the URL directly, using the state's name, you need to use the bang notation. For example:

```
For home: http://localhost/#!home
For state-name: http://localhost/#!state-name
```

Of course, substitute http://localhost by your host + context + whatever you need.